# Google Map API - Infowindow display google place API information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not sure how to go about this.

What I want:
I want to display the information that you might find if you were to go to https://www.google.com/maps and search for the farmers' market.

I want an Info window that provides the address, hours of operation, and possibly additional information that Google Maps provides for this business.

What I have now:
I have an Angular JS code block that populates an array that looks like the following:

```
var locations = [
  ['Findlay Market', 39.115398, -84.518481, 5],
  ['Hyde Park Farmers' Market', 39.139601, -84.442496, 4],
  ['Lettuce Eat Well Farmers' Market', 39.166134, -84.611613, 3],
  ['College Hill Farm Market', 39.195641, -84.545453, 2],
  ['Anderson Farmers' Market', 39.078364, -84.350539, 1]
];
```

Then I use the Infowindow to display the name of the farmers market.

I know that I could add a new table to my database for hours and additional information and use that to create an Angular JS card that I could display in the Infowindow... BUT I was hoping there would be a way to use the Google Map API with the Google Places API to get that information instead of storing it in my database.

Thanks to uksz I was able to use the below code to help me get the information I needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Place details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.115398, -84.518481),
    zoom: 15
});

var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: '500',
    query: 'Findlay Market'
};

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            place: {
                placeId: results[1].place_id,
                location: results[1].geometry.location
            }
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            var content = results[1].name + '<br>' + 
                          results[1].formatted_address + '<br>' +
                          results[1].opening_hours + '<br>' +
                          results[1].place_id + '<br>';
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but if you only want to display the information from Google Places API, you can use theirs getDetails() function. This will return an object. If you don't want to store the object, why not just deleting the object after each time the user for example switches the view? This way you will not store this information in your database, at least not permanently.

Have a good one!

Here is their full getDetails() manual:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests

Comment: Thank you, I was able to better locate a solution using that.